# Import error in python sklearn. Cannot load referenced library

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, importerror, openblas

I'm getting these error when I import sklearn. The ImportError says it cannot load libopenblasp-r0.3.5.dylib. I'm not sure why its not loading.

I create symlinks from other suggestions still cannot figure it out. I used pip to install scikit-learn in macOS.

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .fixes import np_version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 367, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 172, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 641, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

brew info openblas

```
Optimized BLAS library
https://www.openblas.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.6_1 (21 files, 120MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2019-07-24 at 17:27:55
/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.9 (22 files, 119.7MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-03-27 at 13:46:01
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/openblas.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gcc ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
openblas is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides BLAS and LAPACK in the Accelerate framework.

For compilers to find openblas you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include"

For pkg-config to find openblas you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: Please, provide the output of `brew info openblas`. Thanks.

Comment: @sentence Added brew info update

Comment: Are you using virtual environments, or anything similar? (As an aside, my suggestion is to just use Conda, it should help with this kind of situation)

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed like this :

```
python -m venv sklearn-venv
```

then

```
python -m venv sklearn-venv
```

then

```
source sklearn-venv/bin/activate
```

and finally

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

you can check if everything is ok with : 
`python -m pip freeze`